# jquery datepicker: change element attr in beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I would like to set the background-color for the td element the date is shown in the jquery datepicker.
The beforeShowDay method lets me define a class for the corresponding td element but I need to set the corresponding style attribute for the td element as the date objects are related to rgb colors for which I cannot define classes in advance.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I think I misunderstood at first.  I think you mean you want to style the actual cell within the calendar popup.  In that case, you could create a css class on the fly and pass that to the beforeShowDay.  For performance, you could create it with a certain pattern including the name of the input (assuming you have more than one) and check first for its existence and if it already exists just modify the class instead of creating a new one.

And just for fun, an example of how that might work:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDZtG/

There may be a more efficient way, but this does work.

Comment: Ooh, after re-reading, did you mean the actually cell of the day, not the cell that the date picker is located in?

Comment: Yes, I mean the cell of the day.

Comment: See my edit.  This should work I think.  Something like :  `$("<style type='text/css'> .newClass{ background-color:#f00;} </style>").appendTo("head");` and then return whatever className you generate